# Can I apply the formula to the integration?

Tags: integration

Is it possible to use this formula$\int_{}^{}e^{x}cosx = \frac{1}{2}e^{x}(sinx + cosx)$ for $\int_{a}^{b}e^{-2.4x}cos(2x + 0.8)dx$?

Or should we calculate step by step?

Comment: i think an $x$ is missing in the second formula

Comment: yes, sorry I mistook and I modified

Comment: Step by step. Or perhaps you can directly go for a formula of $\int e^{ax}\cos(bx)\,dx$ and $\int e^{ax}\sin (bx)\,dx$ when $a,b\ne 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the $$\int e^{ax}\cos(bx)dx={\frac {a{{\rm e}^{ax}}\cos \left( bx \right) }{{a}^{2}+{b}^{2}}}+{
\frac {{{\rm e}^{ax}}b\sin \left( bx \right) }{{a}^{2}+{b}^{2}}}
$$ if $$a,b\ne 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's pose $t = 2x + 0.8$. Then, $x = \frac{t - 0.8}{2}$
and $dx = \frac{1}{2}dt$.

By substituting, you get: 
$$\int \frac{1}{2}e^{-2.4\frac{t-0.8}{2}}\cos(t)dt  = \frac{1}{2}e^{0.96}\int e^{-1.2t}\cos(t)dt.$$

Now, you can use the formula <s>you know</s> that Dr. Sonnhard Graubner proposed in its post. Finally, substitute back the $x$.

Answer (score 0):

When first calculating complex integrals I would suggest going step by step to ensure you have made no mathematical errors.

Comment: The point is not "safety". The point is that the formula does not apply, nor there is a reasonable algebraic manipulation reducing the problem to an application of that formula. It's like saying that you should not use $b\cdot h$ for the area of a trapezium because you are at risk of making mistakes: damn right you are.

Comment: That's a great point, but in order for students to mathematically understand concepts they MUST struggle and realize why what they're doing is incorrect instead of just providing them with the right formula.

Comment: Again. The point is not whether one way is didactically superior to another - and, arguably, learning to do the appropriate substitution is almost as important as knowing algorithmic procedures: the point is that no reasonable amount of work will allow that person to solve the problem using the other way.